# why local values don't show on my debugger qt creator

Tags: c, debugging, qt-creator

I m a beginner of the language C and I have encountered a issues with the debugger of QT Creator .
It doesn't displays the names and values of the local variables in the space local

Do you have some solution for me please ?

[image]

Comment: Are you compiling with `-g` (debug mode) flag on?

Comment: They have been most probably optimized out. So there is nothing to display.

Comment: So what is the solution to display the variables ? @0___________

Comment: I don't compil with a terminal @DavidRanieri

Comment: @disable otimizations

Comment: how you do it ? @0___________